# Convert operator character to corresponding function

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to convert the characters '+', '-', '*', '/' to the corresponding functions? I mean a function like this (obviously I tried it and it didn't work):

```
toOperator :: Num a => String -> a -> a -> a
toOperator c = read c :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: Not in general. Haskell does not have an `eval` function, and in fact, that information does not even exist at runtime. You *can* create a lookup table for a particular set of functions, though, since functions are first class values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily define a partial function for this purpose with pattern matching

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let f '+' = (+)
Prelude|     f '-' = (-)
Prelude|     f '*' = (*)
Prelude|     f '/' = (/)
Prelude|
Prelude> f '*' 3 4
12.0
Prelude> f '+' 1 2
3.0
Prelude>
```

and the deduced type

```
Prelude> :t f
f :: Fractional a => Char -> a -> a -> a
```